# WIX Major Upgrade : Run a custom action in the second run

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

We have a installation scenario where before doing a major upgrade for the product we need to
`backup` certain configuration/resource files and later sync them.

So we run a custom action to backup files as :

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
..
      <Custom Action='BackupAppFolder' Before="RemoveFiles">
        <![CDATA[(Installed AND NOT REMOVE="ALL") OR (UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)]]>
      </Custom> 
..
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And Major upgrade is scheduled as

```
<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no" DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeMessage)"
              Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"/>
```

'Sync' action is scheduled as

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
..
       <Custom Action='ResourceSync' Before="InstallFinalize">
       (Installed AND NOT REMOVE = "ALL" AND NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED )
             OR (NOT Installed AND WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED)
       </Custom> 
..
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I want to schedule the `ResourceSync` action such that it runs during
-- Repairs / Patches
-- Second Run of Major Upgrades i.e. install of the new product
-- Minor Upgrades

And not run during
-- uninstall
-- fresh installation
-- First run of major upgrade i.e. uninstall of the existing product

Edit : Problem with above is , it runs in the first phase of major upgrade also.

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
REINSTALL OR PATCH OR (WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND NOT REMOVE="ALL")
```

Comment: nope doesn't work..runs in both major upgrade runs..i want it to run in the second run only